# What's Meliodas power level when he can inmobilize Zeldris, Estarrosa and Cusack at the same time?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

In episode 17th of season #3 of the Nanatsu no Taizai anime series, Meliodas is able to inmobilize Zeldris, Estarrosa and Cusack at the same time, 3 of the most powerful demons . Which is Meliodas power level when he's able to do this?

Answer (score 1):

At the time, Meliodas is in *Assault Mode*. In Volume 29, we learn that Assault Mode!Meliodas power level is 142 000. Unfortunately, a breakdown of that power level wasn't provided.

Comment: though that shouldn't be enough to immobilize Cusack since he has like ~180